# Advise how to create an object of a certain particle effects

Tags: three.js

I have an object in the blender with the vertices and faces, I upload using the loader, and now I want to create particles with coordinates randomly and at a certain speed that the particles move to the top of the object and filled.

I want to get something like this as a result of on this [site](https://baconclubhouse.no/).

Advise please which way to look, can have libraries that make this possibility even easier.

Comment: I have an [example](http://www.smartjava.org/tjscb/06-particles-postprocessing/06.01-create-particle-system-from-geometry.html), I have not found a sandbox where you can transfer this [example](http://www.smartjava.org/tjscb/06-particles-postprocessing/06.01-create-particle-system-from-geometry.html), I want to implement a similar effect with a cow

Comment: [cow model](http://www.smartjava.org/tjscb/assets/models/cow/cowTM08New00RTime02.obj)